# what is 'PDO::lastInsertId() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

The title really construes my question.
So i was working on Laravel and processing the input of a form, when i kept on getting this error in my log on the line where there is insertion into the database.

`PDO::lastInsertId() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

What does it mean? I mean, can anyone explain PDO::lastInsertId() and where it comes in play?

Comment: *"`PDO::lastInsertId() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`
What does it mean?"* - It means show us more code.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: _...pass the beer_ - FTFY :)